# How to set directory result robot framework in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, automated-tests, robotframework

Situation

1.My script in robot framework has keyword web capture screenshots
${outputdir}

2.New jobs jenkins freestyle > run 12 AM everyday

3.checkout from git

4.Config publish robot results

5.When run robot > img,log,report will be in workspace

I want to create folder in build folder and set img,log,report will be in 
..\builds\$BUILD_NUMBER\newfloder

What should I do? 
Thanks

Comment: please help for solution

Answer (score 0):

```sh
robot --help
```

will give you all options for running robot. In those docs:

```
 -d --outputdir dir       Where to create output files. The default is the
                          directory where tests are run from and the given path
                          is considered relative to that unless it is absolute.
```

So, adding `--outputdir /where/you/want/to/store/the/stuff` to your robot invocation should help.